# How to Split a List into two to populate differnt listviews?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I have a list that gets populated by a API but now i want to split the list into two so i can populate two different listview on the same screen how can i do this?

```
items = new List<TableItem> ();
items.Add (new TableItem (){ SubProfileName = "Apple" });
items.Add (new TableItem (){ SubProfileName = "Pear" });
items.Add (new TableItem (){ SubProfileName = "Shoe" });
items.Add (new TableItem (){ SubProfileName = "Cake" });
items.Add (new TableItem (){ SubProfileName = "Vodka" });
items.Add (new TableItem (){ SubProfileName = "Alize" });
.......
.......
.......
listView = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.ListViewForSubProfiles);
listView.Adapter = new SelectProfileAdapter(this, items);
```

Comment: It depends on how exactly you want to split it

Comment: @ I want to split it evenly between listviews

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [GetRange()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/21k0e39c.aspx) method to get part of a List, so in your example you need to know how many items you want in each group to split them properly, but let's say you have 10 items and you want to put 5 in each ListView, you can do this:

```
List<TableItem> firstList = items.GetRange(0, 5);
List<TableItem> secondList = items.GetRange(5, 5);
```

If you want to jump ahead, you can just the list when you set the adapter:

```
listView.Adapter = new SelectProfileAdapter(this, items.GetRange(startIndex, numItems));
```

Comment: is there anyway i can count the items in a list then split it depending on that number?

Comment: @ShayalSingh sure you can use [items.Count](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/27b47ht3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)